# How do I keep a set of working commits that I can apply on to two different branches?

Tags: git

tl;dr How do I keep a working set of commits that I can carry between two branches (we may assume that the commits apply cleanly to both)

### Use Case

I have a `master` branch and `refactor` branch. I have some debugging information that I am printing between the two. I would like to commit my debugging information for the usual reasons why we do version control.

### Method I use currently

```
git checkout -b refactor
# edit some files here
git add -p path/to/refactored/file.c
git commit -m "the refactor"
git stash -m "my debugging stuff"

git checkout master
git stash pop
bin/run/my/program

git stash
git checkout refactor
git stash pop
bin/run/my/program

vimdiff logs/master logs/refactor
```

### Problem

The stash feels very precarious and I don't have that much control over my debug history as I move through the cycle of making `refactor` match `master`

### Solution

If I could add another branch `masterX` and another branch `refactorX` with all the debugging commits being common to them then I can develop cleanly in such a way that `refactorX` always contains all the debug commits that I want *and* all the updates to `refactor` and when I add code to `refactor`, I want `refactorX` to stay up to date.

I can sort of do this by some combination of `rebase` and then always rebasing `refactorX` onto `refactor` and so on while keeping my debug commits on some X branch and then merging into both `masterX` and `refactorX`.

But I'm hoping someone else has an ergonomic solution to this.

Comment: "The stash feels very precarious" Because you're using it in precarious way. You keep erasing it.  Give your stash a name so you can find it later, and `apply` it instead of `pop` so you don't keep erasing it.

Comment: I do give it a name with `git stash -m whatever` but if I `pop` it at any time, I'm in trouble. Plus I'd like to be able to use the stash for other things during that time too. And I do want the ergonomics of `pop` over `apply`+`drop` or `show` + `drop`.

The equivalent for `pop` is quite a lot of actions for commits and recovering from reflog is easy even then. Plus, altering the stashed contents does not have a history tree I can walk through.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand any of that, sorry.